# How do i sort a .csv file in python?

Tags: python

The problem I'm having is that for some reason it prints from another file. I'm not really sure how to describe it but basically i have 2 files one named songlist.csv and the other scoreboard.csv. I want to sort the scoreboard.csv by highest score achieved. This line

```py
scoreboardSorted = sorted(scoreboard, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
```

is supposed to sort the file scoreboard.csv but it doesn't, then in the next line

```py
for score in scoreboardSorted:
       print(str(score[0]) + ": " + str(score[1]) + " points")
       a = a + 1
       if a == 5:
           break
   sys.exit()
```

it prints from another file which is called songlist.csv. I need help on how to sort the list to show the top 5 scores in scoreboard.csv and not print from songlist.csv.

```
def endGame(points):
    scoreboard = []
    # Write score to scoreboard
    with open("scoreboard.csv", "a") as scoreboardFile:
        scoreboardWriter = csv.writer(scoreboardFile)
        scoreboardWriter.writerow([name, points])
    # Open scoreboard in read mode and store in memory
    scoreboardFile = open("scoreboard.csv", "rt")
    scoreboardReader = csv.reader(scoreboardFile)
    for i in scoreboardReader:
        scoreboard.append(row)
    print("\nGame over!")
    print("Well done " + str(name) + ", you got " + str(points) + " points.")
    print("\nTop 5:")
    # Sort list
    scoreboardSorted = sorted(scoreboard, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
    # Print first 5
    a = 0
    for score in scoreboardSorted:
        print(str(score[0]) + ": " + str(score[1]) + " points")
        a = a + 1
        if a == 5:
            break
    sys.exit()
```

The result is this and I'm not sure why this is happening.

```py
Top 5:
Avicii: Lonely Together points
Avicii: Lonely Together points
Avicii: Lonely Together points
Avicii: Lonely Together points
Avicii: Lonely Together points
```

P.S I'm sorry but I'm not sure how to describe my problem that well.

Comment: Neither of the Name of this thread, the code you've provided or the description of the problem seems to have anything to do with each other. Please edit this question so that it better describes what problems you have.

Comment: @HampusLarsson I'm not sure why this is happening my self. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on the specific problem that you're having, but in Python to get the sorted version of an iterable you can use the function `sorted()`

For example:

```
l = ['blah', 'foo', 'hi']
x = sorted(l)
```

will result in x containing the list `['blah', 'foo', 'hi']`, which has been sorted alphabetically.

You can also give a key, so this:

```
l = ['blah', 'foo', 'hi']
x = sorted(l, key=lambda a: len(a))
```

will result in x containing the list `['hi', 'foo', 'blah']`, which has been sorted by the length of the element instead of alphabetically.

Not sure if this quite answers what you were asking, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I know how to sort a list. The problem I'm having is that for some reason it prints from another file. I'm not really sure how to describe it but basically i have 2 files one named songlist.csv and the other scoreboard.csv. I want to sort the scoreboard.csv by highest score achieved. Instead it prints from songlist.csv/